# Create a pipe for mascara for input text example 00.00

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to create an angled pipe 4 for a type text input which, when typing, should insert a dot between the characters.

the input receives 4 characters and must enter a dot by dividing the 4 characters.

For example, 0000 should be displayed as 00.00

This is being done, but if I paste a value greater than 4 characters, I would like to not allow and leave the field empty.

**Pipe**

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({name: 'tarifa'})
export class TarifaPipe implements PipeTransform{

    transform(value: string): string {

        if (!value) {
            return '';
        }

        var tarifaValor = value.replace(/\D/g, '');

        if (tarifaValor.length !== 4) {
            return value;
        }

        var tarifaLista = tarifaValor.match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})$/);

        if (tarifaLista && tarifaLista.length === 3) {
            value = tarifaLista[1] + '.' + tarifaLista[2];
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `if (tarifaValor.length > 4) { return false; }`?

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({name: 'tarifa'})
export class TarifaPipe implements PipeTransform{

 transform(value: string): string {
    //since you want to set it to '' when input value is > 4 chars.
    if (!value || value.length !== 4 || value.match(/^[0-9]+$/) == null) {
        return '';
    } else {
        var tarifaValor = value.replace(/\D/g, '');
        //you need to change your previous regex from `/^(\d{2})(\d{2})$/` to make it work for value with length 2,3,4.
        //if the input value is not always restricted to 4 you can use regex /^(\d{0,2})(\d{2})$/ and change above if cond `value.length > 4`
        var tarifaLista = tarifaValor.match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})$/);
      if (tarifaLista && tarifaLista.length === 3) {
        value = tarifaLista[1] + '.' + tarifaLista[2];
      }
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

for value = 234, output will be 2.34
for value = 2345, output will be 23.45
for value = 23456, output will be ''

you can make use of HTML input maxlength attribute to restrict the input field to accept max 4 chars.
`maxlength="4"`

Comment: Many thanks for the Avinash answer. In my case I field should always be filled with 2 numerics before the point and 2 after the point, as in its example for value = 2345, output will be 23.45. Only this format should be allowed otherwise you would like to clear the field.
With the code of your response I got this behavior by changing the regex to the first form that was according to your comment in the code. The problem I'm having is that if you paste the input a value 22222 the field accepts and would like to clear the field for non-standard value.

Comment: you can use maxlength attribute on the input field `maxlength="4"` to restrict to a max length of 4 characters.Also i changed my ans as the value is now only 4 chars

Comment: Also use `value.match(/^[0-9]+$/) == null` in the if cond to check if only numbers are there in `value`

Comment: But once, thanks to Avinash's response, it worked perfectly, thank you. I also set my maxlength to 4. I identified a behavior when pasting a value for the input. Example, if paste "Ctrl v" a value of 0000 the mask is applied perfectly, but if I do not clear the entry and just select the integer value and paste "Ctrl v" that same value 0000, the mask does not apply. Do I have to deal with another event? 

And if I paste a value "Ctrl v" already masked example 00.00 the value is displaying as 00.0, I believe it is on account of maxlength 4

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to ensure that the sting is always 4 digits, and use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) to remove the padding after splitting it, like:

```
transform(value: string): string {

    var tarifaValor = value.replace(/\D/g, '');

    // if it is blank or over 4 digits, return blank
    if (tarifaValor.length < 1 || tarifaValor.length > 4) {
        return '';
    }

    // Pad with zeros to make 4 digits:
    tarifaValor = tarifaValor.padStart(4, '0');

    var tarifaLista = tarifaValor.match(/^(\d{2})(\d{2})$/);

    // Use parseInt on first match to trim leading zeros.
    value = parseInt(tarifaLista[1]).toString() + '.' + tarifaLista[2];

    return value;
}
```

results:

for value = 1, output will be 0.01

for value = 12, output will be 0.12

for value = 123, output will be 1.23

for value = 1234, output will be 12.34

for value = 12345, output will be ''

Comment: Thanks for the response Anthony. The code displays the message Property 'padStart' does not exist on type 'string'. in the code snippetValue.padStart (4, '0');

Comment: `padStart` is a function, not a property.  Your example looks like `padStart (4, '0')` with a space between the function name and the opening parentheses. Is that what you are actually testing instead of `padStart(4, '0')` (no space between)?

Comment: Thanks for the response Anthony. Not my example, in my code I do not use this function I copied its response code and appeared this error message as it showed in the first comment I made.

Comment: How are you testing the code? Where are you seeing the error you mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, thought that padString mutated the actual string, but it returns the modified string instead. Updated code to `tarifaValor = tarifaValor.padStart(4,"0");` Here's a demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p8yLko94/14/